# Swift Best Practices - how / when to check for internet connection and 404s when working with APIs

Tags: ios, swift, api

There are a wealth of resources for checking for a valid Internet connection with Swift (Reachability) and also ways to check the statusCode of the httpResponse when making an API call, but what is the "right" way to check and handle these errors (Internet not reachable, server 404) when dealing with an API heavy iOS app?

For example, when the app starts in the initial view (or AppDelegate I suppose) one can check for both and redirect to a "ServerProblemsViewController" that displays a message (or show an alert, though those can be dismissed).  But what happens is someone is in the middle of using your app and the Internet drops or the server becomes unreachable?  How would you handle this?

I am wondering if devs typically check for Reachability before EVERY API call and check the return status of EVERY API call, or somehow encapsulate that logic into a helper function?

How do experienced iOS devs deal with this situation?

Comment: FYI - this really has nothing to do with Swift. The best practices you seek apply to any language.

Comment: Valid point but if there are any code examples I would like them in Swift 2.0.  I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I check for reachability on every call and then examine the response status code by type casting the NSURLResponse to an NSHTTPURLResponse (which has a `statusCode` property). And yes, my requests use the same base class to encapsulate all of the functionality--only creating derived classes when needed. You can use the reachability example code from Apple which has been ported to Swift and can be typically found on Github through the community. Simply reading through this repo will probably answer a lot of your questions about changes in reachability. Notifications FTW!: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

Comment: Great thx. How do you handle when you are making multiple calls in a row?  For example the initial view controller makes three api calls. If I encapsulate the check logic then all three would hit the same logic.  Do you also have some kind of utility wrapper function that you wrap multiple API calls around?  Also what do you use to check if the host is reaponding, i.e. api.example.com?  Thx

Comment: It can get pretty complicated. You can cancel subsequent requests if one fails and you have more to process. In that case, you probably want to be using an `NSOperationQueue`. And while it's true, they're all hitting the same code, they are all running asynchronously in their own thread via `NSOperation`. That's why you should use `NSOperationQueue` so you can see how many more operations are left to run. Alternatively, you can make your `NSOperationQueue` a serial queue by limiting it to one operation at a time using its `maxConcurrentOperationCount` property.

Comment: And I don't know if there is a best practice for a host to check for reachability. I typically use a website of my own that I'm reasonably certain is up all the time.